# Passing data from activity to fragment in android is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

I want to pass parameters from activity to fragment.
This is the code from the activity:

```
public class MatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
        MarqueFragment fragobj = new MarqueFragment();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

    }

}
```

This is the code from the fragment:

```
public class MarqueFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        View convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_marque, container, false);


            if (getArguments() != null) {
                String mParam1 = getArguments().getString("edttext");
                System.out.println("got this from MatchActivity "+mParam1);
            }else{
                System.out.println("got nothing");
            }     
}
```

I am not getting any arguments I don't know why.
Notice : am not getting an error am getting "got nothing" as output.

Comment: The output is "got nothing" or some error?

Comment: the output is " got nothing "  not an error

Comment: And what is the android version you are using?

Comment: Mean `getArguments()` is null.

Comment: getArguments() is null yes

Comment: You are only showing the Fragment code but not how you are adding it. Could you show the full code? (with the FragmentTransaction)

Comment: show code fo swaping fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(edttext", "From Activity");
MarqueFragment fragobj = new MarqueFragment();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_marque, fragobj);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: still no parameters passed even after i moved the code in the onCreate

Comment: fraginfo is unkown variable !!

Comment: transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_marque, fragobj);
 wrong second parameter here

Comment: wrong second argument expecting android.app.fragment